# Toast/Popup on tvOS

Tags: popup, uikit, toast, tvos

I've recently come across a native Toast-like notification on tvOS, as seen in the image below:

[image: tvOS Screenshot 1]

Is there any way for us to display notifications to the users like that? I am only aware of the native `UIAlertController` and two external libraries on GitHub [here](https://github.com/svtek/TVOSToast) and [here](https://github.com/toshi0383/Toast).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public UIKit class for this. You'll need to roll your own implementation or use a third parties.

If you'd like Apple to make this accessible you can submit a request through [Apple Bug Reporter](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/)

> With Apple Bug Reporter, you can submit bug reports and **request enhancements** to APIs and developer tools.

Comment: I was afraid that this would be the case. Thanks for responding!